# Where is the window outlet in an NSDocument

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

My app was converted from a non-document-based app to a document-based one. I did that by creating a subclass of `NSDocument`, called `Document`. I also created a `Document.xib` and set its "File's Owner" to `Document`.

Now in `Document.xib`, I can see there is a `window` outlet in its "File's Owner". I don't have a `window` outlet defined in `Document`. Where does it come from? I guess it is from the super class `NSDocument`, but I have no access to that variable in `Document`. What's up with this weird `window` outlet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation for `-[NSDocument setWindow:]`

> This method is invoked automatically during the loading of any nib for which this document is the file’s owner, if the file’s owner window outlet is connected in the nib. You should not invoke this method directly, and typically you would not override it either.

`NSDocument` doesn't deal with `NSWindow`s directly, but it keeps a list of `NSWindowController`s that you can access via the `-[NSDocument windowControllers]` method. My guess is that when `setWindow:` gets called, it wraps the window in a new `NSWindowController` and adds it to the list.

You should be able to access the window with something like this:

```
NSWindowController* controller = self.windowControllers.lastObject;
NSWindow* window = controller.window;
```

I just made a new project to test it, and this works:

```
- (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *)aController {
    [super windowControllerDidLoadNib:aController];
    NSLog(@"%@", [self.windowControllers.lastObject window]);
}
```

Comment: I tried `aController.window` and your suggested `self.windowControllers.lastObject.window` in `windowControllerDidLoadNib:` but both return `nil`

Comment: @Ethan I just tested it, and it works for me with the edit above.

Comment: Ahh..Thank you! I figured out what was wrong in my code. When I was fiddling with that `window` outlet, I declared a `window` property in my `Document` and forgot to remove it. This caused `self.windowControllers.lastObject.window` to be nil somehow (I don't know why).